# Should I delete either credential.helper=store or credential.helper=manager to avoid to type in my credentials every time?

Tags: git, credentials, git-config, credential-manager

It's a while I don't push code on my github account.

Today as I tryed to

```
git push -u origin master
```

my command prompt (Anaconda) asked me to type in my github username and password

> Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
>
> Username for 'https://github.com/': myusername
>
> Password for 'https://myusername@github.com/':

I typed those in, and then the prompt responded with:

> fatal: unable to get credential storage lock: File exists

I can push the code with no problem, but I would prefer that I don't have to type in my user and password every time.

I did a bit search and I found out the error I am having is ponted out in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505843/fatal-unable-to-get-credential-storage-lock-file-exists), where it is suggested that the error is caused by having more than one `credential.helper=` code line in git configurations. It is also suggested that by leaving just one of these lines, it adjusts the error.

So, by typing

> git config --list

I found out that I have two code lines `credential.helper=` in my .git/config file.
One is in system **config** file, and one in global **config** file

```
git config --list --system
```

> credential.helper=manager

```
git config --list --global
```

> credential.helper=store

But in my .git/config file I can't find any line starting with `credential.helper=`.

So where can I find these lines?

And Should I delete either `credential.helper=store` or `credential.helper=manager` to avoid to type in my credentials every time?

Answer (score 3):

There is a stuck `.git-credentials.lock` file in your home directory. It probably contains your password in plaintext, so you should remove it.

[`git-credential-store`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store):

> Using this helper will store your passwords unencrypted on disk,
>   protected only by filesystem permissions. If this is not an acceptable
>   security tradeoff, try git-credential-cache, or find a helper that
>   integrates with secure storage provided by your operating system.

You should stick to the OS provided `manager`.

You can show which file a setting is coming from by using the `--show-origin` option of `git config`.

But you can also remove it with the command `git config --unset --global credential.helper`.